# React: TS2786: cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components, adyen

Good evening, so I'm current trying Adyen Web Components which has it's own pre-built card user interface. But after implementing the code below, I get

- TS2786: 'Card' cannot be used as a JSX component.
- Its return type 'Promise' is not a valid JSX element.
- Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

I'm not sure how to fix this typescript error, I have updated the package.json but i'm not sure what exacly to do.

Any help is appreciated.

```
const Card = async (): Promise<JSX.Element> => {
    function handleOnChange(state, component) {
        
     state.isValid // True or false. Specifies if all the information that the shopper provided is valid.
        
              state.data // Provides the data that you need to pass in the `/payments` call.
        
              component // Provides the active component instance that called this event.
        
          }
        
        
        
          const configuration = {
        
              locale: "en_US",
        
              environment: "test",
        
              clientKey: "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY",
        
              onChange: handleOnChange
        
          };
          
          const checkout = await AdyenCheckout(configuration);
        
          const customCard = checkout.create('securedfields', {
        
            // Optional configuration
        
            type: 'card',
        
            brands: ['mc', 'visa', 'amex', 'bcmc', 'maestro'],
        
            styles: {
        
                error: {
        
                    color: 'red'
        
                },
        
                validated: {
        
                    color: 'green'
        
                },
        
                placeholder: {
        
                    color: '#d8d8d8'
        
                }
        
            },
        
            // Only for Web Components before 4.0.0.
        
            // For Web Components 4.0.0 and above, configure aria-label attributes in translation files
        
            ariaLabels: {
        
                lang: 'en-GB',
        
                encryptedCardNumber: {
        
                    label: 'Credit or debit card number field',
        
                    iframeTitle: 'Iframe for secured card number',
        
                    error: 'Message that gets read out when the field is in the error state'
        
                }
        
            },
        
            // Events
        
            onChange: function() {},
        
            onValid : function() {},
        
            onLoad: function() {},
        
            onConfigSuccess: function() {},
        
            onFieldValid : function() {},
        
            onBrand: function() {},
        
            onError: function() {},
        
            onFocus: function() {},
        
            onBinValue: function(bin) {},
        
            onBinLookup: function(callbackObj: CbObjOnBinLookup) {}
        
        }).mount('#customCard-container');
        
          return (
            <>
            <div id="customCard-container">
        <label>
        
            <span>Card number:</span>
        
            <span data-cse="encryptedCardNumber"></span>
        
        </label>
        
        <label>
        
            <span>Expiry date:</span>
        
            <span data-cse="encryptedExpiryDate"></span>
        
        </label>
        
        <label>
        
            <span>CVV/CVC:</span>
        
            <span data-cse="encryptedSecurityCode"></span>
        
        </label>
        
        </div>
        </>
          );
        }
        
        export default Card;
```

Comment: React components cannot be async functions. I'm unfamiliar with AdyenCheckout, but most likely, that code needs to be moved into a `useEffect`, and then set state when it completes.

Comment: Ahh i see, I decided to put it into an async function and activate it with useEffect. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.